# Refreshing token through msal.js

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using Azure AD B2C for my React.js app and I've noticed that after a while, all user requests are getting rejected by my API as unauthorized.

I'm pretty sure the issue is that the `jwt` token expires. I'm using `msal.js` to get my token from Azure AD B2C.

I found a short paragraph on Microsoft Docs but couldn't find any examples. Also my research indicates I need to open up a new windows and manually make an HTTP request. Is this correct?

Could someone tell me where I can find some examples of this?

Comment: Are you doing some caching for the token? If you call the acquireToken APIs on MSAL.JS you should always get a valid token. It does caching by itself and if the token is expired, it will automatically get a new token using a hidden iframe.

Comment: I don't cache anything and it's clearly not automatically refreshing the token. When the user clicks to login to the app, he/she gets redirected to Azure AD B2C and comes back with the token stored in session storage. That's all I'm currently doing. Could you tell me where I can find some sample code that shows me what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Always call `acquireTokenSilent` before you call your API. Let MSAL do the caching, refreshing etc., that is what it is for. Fallback to AcquireTokenPopup or similar if silent fails.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp

```
    function callApi() {
        clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
            callApiWithAccessToken(accessToken);
        }, function (error) {
            clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                callApiWithAccessToken(accessToken);
            }, function (error) {
                logMessage("Error acquiring the access token to call the Web api:\n" + error);
            });
        })
    }
```

Side note: For `acquireTokenSilent`, MSAL is actually creating a hidden iframe to acquire the token, which might be what you are referring to in your question.